# Wildfly provisioning with galleon. Missing batch (jberet)

Tags: wildfly, sti, jberet, s2i

I tried to build a minimal Wildfly distribution with galleon with s2i which turned out pretty well so far.
But now my application has missing dependencies for batch.

So I tried to add `batch` to `GALLEON_PROVISION_LAYERS` but it seems there is no batch layer.

Here is my simplyfied s2i:

```
s2i build http://myrepository quay.io/wildfly/wildfly-centos7:latest wildflytest  --env GALLEON_PROVISION_LAYERS=datasources-web-server,jaxrs-server,cloud-server,keycloak,observability,h2-driver,h2-datasource,batch  --env ARTIFACT_DIR=subdir/target --env MODULE_DIR=subdir
```

Am i just missing the right layer to user batch or do i need to use a full wildfly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no layer for batch yet, you must use the default config.

Comment: is this feature planned or can request such a feature?

Comment: Hi, we have a WildFly JIRA issue to track it: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-13128 and work in progress.